# Count how many integers are in the text file using fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

For example, I have a txt file with all integers. I want to count how many **integers** there are in order to allocate an array.

```
int array[0];
int count = 0;
FILE *file = fopen("file1.txt","r");
while(fscanf(file,"%d",&array[count])==1){
  count++;
}
printf("%d",count);
```

Currently there are error messages and won't go through. Is this the way fscanf work?

Comment: "there are error messages" ? which ones? compilation time or run time?

Comment: Check `fopen` works. Why are you using `array`. Segment fault there

Comment: Please check if `file` is not `NULL`

Comment: @EdHeal `int array[0];` Whaaaat?

Comment: I did not write the code.  Thinking `array [count]` is going to be the problem

Comment: "I want to count how many integers " --> Is there anything other than integers in the file like  `"123 x 456"`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an array of size 0. If you want to only count the number of integers, don't use an array, but only a temporary variable.
*It is a good idea to check whether you opened the file correctly and to close the file too.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int temp;
  int count = 0;
  FILE *file = fopen("file1.txt","r");
  if(file == NULL){
    printf("Could not open specified file");
    return -1;
  }
  while(fscanf(file,"%d",&temp)==1){
    count++;
  }
  fclose(file);
  printf("%d",count);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

If you also want to store the values for later use, you could for example read through the file twice, first time counting the amount of integers, then using this amount to declare the needed array. An important thing before the second run is to rewind the file pointer, to read the file from the start.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int temp;
  int count = 0;
  FILE *file = fopen("file1.txt","r");
  if(file == NULL){
    printf("Could not open specified file");
    return -1;
  }
  while(fscanf(file,"%d",&temp)==1){
    count++;
  }

  printf("%d",count);

  if(count == 0){  //do not create array of size 0
    fclose(file);
  }
  else{
    //second run
    int array[count];
    rewind(file);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
      fscanf(file,"%d",&array[count]);
    }
    fclose(file);

    //continue using array...
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gplease add the check that you can open the file

Comment: @EdHeal thanks for the mention, I updated the answer

Comment: Minor: missing corner case: If `count == 0`, `int array[count];` should be avoided.

Comment: @chux Thank you for pointing it out. I have made a change in the code, but now the scope is restricted, which is, well... less pretty :D

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[0];
```

and

```
fscanf(file,"%d",&array[count])
```

will lead to a segmentation fault because you're accessing the array out of bounds.

If you need flexible array you need

- `int *array`
- a place-holder for storing each number from `fscanf`
- `realloc` array every time you find a new number and add the number to array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define isDigit(c) ('0' <= (c) && (c) <= '9') ? 1 : 0

int main() {
    FILE *fd;
    int counter, c, tmp;
    if ((fd = fopen("PathToFile", "r")) != NULL){
        do{
            c = getc(fd);
            if (isDigit(c)) tmp = 1;
            else if (tmp == 1 && !isDigit(c)){
            counter++, tmp = 0;
            }
        }while (c != EOF);
    }else{
        printf("Couldn't find File!");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fd);
    printf("%i", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: If the file consisted of `"-123 456"`, this approach would report 6.  I'd expect 2.  Yet OP is a bit unclear as to the goals.

Comment: @chux I agree with you to expect 2. OP said he wanted to count **integers**, not digits.

Comment: Thanks I edited to fix the digit issue. However there are better solutions already